# Why do my Gmod mods not load?

Tags: garrys-mod

I subscribed to all of these addons, but they don't load when I start the game. How do I fix this? I really need help! I just want to keep my mods loaded because I have to reload them every time.

Answer (score 1):

When you start gmod, there should be a semi-transparent rectangle at the bottom of the screen (in the main menu) that shows the mod you are downloading.  If you do not see that when you start gmod it either could be A) The mod has already finished downloading/installing.  B) You are not subscribed to the mod.  Double check you are subscribed to the mod.  If you are indeed subscribed, and you still don't see the mod, try validating the files through steam.